# jQuery.text() to get html price and to increase it with number field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

How can I get the numeric price? Simple products have:

```
<td class="wh-price">                           
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>425.00</span>                       
</td>
```

Wholesale products have:

```
    <td class="wh-price">                           
        <del class="original-computed-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>625.00</span></del>

        <span style="display: block;" class="wholesale_price_container">
            <span class="wholesale_price_title"></span>
            <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>54,321.00</span></ins>
        </span>
    </td>
```

**Need the price for simple and wholesale (`<ins>` price; not the `<del>` price) products so when the quantity increased I can calculate them.**

Quantity HTML:

```
    <td class="quantity-field">
        <div class="quantity">
            <input step="1" min="" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" type="number">
        </div>
    </td>
```

I have tried this jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".qty").on('change',function() {
        setPriceQ();
      });
    })
    const setPriceQ = function(){
      $.each(
        $('tr[data-role="product"]'),
        function(index,element){
          const $el = $(element);
          const originalPrice = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text();
          const totalQuantity = $el.find(".qty").val();            
          $el.find('#result').html( originalPrice * totalQuantity );
        }
      );
    };
```

But it's not working and most of the time showing `$NaN`
So I tried `const originalPrice = parseInt($el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text(), 10);`

Still not working. In my guess `.text()` is getting `<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>` which is preventing the parsing.

The html code is generated with php `<?php echo $product->get_price_html() ?>`; for simple products I can get only numeric value without markup by using `<?php echo $product->get_price() ?>` but for wholesale products price it's not possible by simple php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys, from your answers I have come up with my own code. This is working for me perfectly.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".qty").on('change',function() {
        setPriceQ();
      });
    })

    const setPriceQ = function(){
      $.each(
        $('tr[data-role="product"]'),
        function(index,element){
          const $el = $(element);

          const originalPriceStr = $el.find('.wh-price .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, "");
          const originalPrice = parseFloat(originalPriceStr, 10);

          const wholesalePriceStr = $el.find('.wh-price .wholesale_price_container .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, "");
          const wholesalePrice = parseFloat(wholesalePriceStr, 10);   

          const totalQuantity = $el.find(".qty").val();

          if($el.find('.wholesale_price_container').length){
              $el.find('#result').html( '$' + ( wholesalePrice * totalQuantity ) .toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1," ) );
           }
          else {
              $el.find('#result').html( '$' + ( originalPrice * totalQuantity ) .toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1," ) );    
           }
          }
        );
      };
```

Comment: update the jquery to .find('.original-computed-price .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount') notice the space

Comment: @N-ate Ans Updated; need a `if` to check whether `.wh-price .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` has any value or `.wh-price .wholesale_price_container .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount` has value

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using the `replace()` function:

```
const originalPriceStr = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[$,]/g, ''));
const originalPrice = parseFloat(originalPriceStr, 10);
```

Also, you might want to use `parseFloat` instead, in case there are cents, you don't want to create rounding errors.

Comment: I fixed my answer, it will work now. I changed it to `replace(/[$,]/g, ''))` so that it matches both the `$` and the `,` using a "regular expression".

Answer (score 1):

You could do the .text().replace() if you would like, but that will only work if you know the currency symbol you are trying to .replace().

I would add a `<span data-role-price>425.00</span>` around the price and then select it `$el.find('[data-role-price]').text()`

That is just my personal preference on how to solve the problem even though it adds some additional HTML, the good news is that it is currency agnostic.

If you can't modify the HTML then you can do this which is also currency agnostic

```
const currencySymbol = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol');
const originalPriceWithSymbol = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text();
const originalPriceWithoutSymbol = originalPriceWithSymbol.replace(currencySymbol, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better to use a mix of jquery and native functions.
JQuery automatically filters out text nodes from the result collections, but using

```
$el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()[0].childNodes[1].textContent
```

You can get the exact text node for your value.
It supports all currencies and does not require markup changes.

Comment: Using it shows the full price $2,000.00. The $ sign is the childNode, using this `$el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()[0].childNodes[0].textContent` only shows the `$` . I need the numeric value to calculate.

Comment: So `$el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()[0].childN‌​odes[0].textContent` shows `$`, but `$el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()[0].childN‌​odes[1].textContent` shows `$2,000.00` ?? Do you have two $ signs in your markup?

Comment: What are you testing it against? I don't see $2,000.00 in your example above.

Comment: Here, check out the console output. I've used your markup. https://jsfiddle.net/bsalex/k95we4ep/4/

Comment: `const woo = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').get()[0].childNodes[1].textContent;` `$el.find('.resultWithWoo').html( woo * 10 );`
I want to multiply it with the quantity number field

Comment: Try changing this `$el.find('.resultWithWoo').html( woo * 10 );` to this `$el.find('.resultWithWoo').html( parseFloat(woo, 10) * 10 );`

Comment: I think that the problem is in `,`. Use this `$el.find('.resultWithWoo').html( parseFloat(woo.replace(',', ''), 10) * 10 );`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.substring(1)`

```js
var text = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().substring(1);
console.log(parseFloat(text).toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>425.00</span>
```

**Note:** this code just to return the price from the text instead of NAN .. but I think the problem not just this one, You need to show the `.qty` and where it is?

**Update:** If the part of code in your answer works and you need to check from where the price come you can use `if($el.find('.wholesale_price_container').length)` this code check for *If there is any div with class `wholesale_price_container` already exists if yes get the whole price from it and set the totalQuantity to 1 because no need for it*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".qty").on('change',function() {
    setPriceQ();
  });
})
const setPriceQ = function(){
  $.each(
    $('tr[data-role="product"]'),
    function(index,element){
      const $el = $(element);

      const originalPriceStr = $el.find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, "");
      const originalPrice = parseFloat(originalPriceStr, 10);

      const totalQuantity = $el.find(".qty").val();

      if($el.find('.wholesale_price_container').length){
         originalPriceStr = $el.find('.wholesale_price_container').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text().replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, "");
         originalPrice = parseFloat(originalPriceStr, 10);
         totalQuantity = 1;
      }

      $el.find('#result').html( originalPrice * totalQuantity );     

      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: updated my original question and posted an answer with current problem, can you please take a look into it.

Comment: needed to edit some parts of the code you provided, now it's working like a charm now. See my updated answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you'll want to parse money for the result of text like so:

```
..text().match(/([0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}|[0-9]+)/)[0];
```

Comment: Can you share the source text, so I can test the regex? I'll fix any errors and update the answer.

Comment: please see the answer I posted, currently this is only the problem.